# Access Router website of remote VPN

Tags: router, vpn, openvpn

I recently set up a OpenVPN server with a Raspberry PI using https://www.datenreise.de/raspberry-pi-vpn-server-einrichten-anleitung/ . This works quite good.

But now I would like to access the router web site (e.g. `192.168.2.1` ) where the Raspberry (so where the VPN Server is) is located being connected to the VPN. If I try navigating to `192.168.2.1` I just get to the router website of the local network I'm physically connected but not the one from the remote network.
Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: It's a routing issue. Your computer knows it is physically connected to the local network, e.g. 192.168.2.1 and so it assumes all requests to 192.168.2.X (where X can be 1-254) are local out the physical Ethernet adapter. You need to tell it to send those requests to the VPN interface. So for example you could say, at the command line "route add 192.168.2.0 mask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.8.0.1" assuming 10.8.0.1 is the IP of your Pi and that your client is running Linux.

Comment: Thank you very much, instead of doing it on the command line I did it within the OpenVPN config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Curtis pointed out it was a routing issue. I just added a route in the `.ovpn` OpenVPN configuration file to tell OpenVPN to also route that local address to the VPN network:

```
route 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.255
```